# TableView in landscape mode in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an iPhone app and there is a table in the landscape view where I added a text field so as the user will input data, on iPhone 4, the user can click on all cells and columns  and enter the text, BUT on iPhone 5, the table is NOT clickable in the first 2 columns (landscape view)! Any idea how why and how to make the first 2 columns clickable? 
[image]
Plz see attachment .
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Actually your app is not in landscape mode, if it is in landscape mode the status bar will be in landscape not portrait. So only the frames for remaining cells are not set.

Comment: Thank you  Manimaran, I did rotate for the view using this code  CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);
    [self.VisiteView setTransform:rotate];How I can set the remaining cells?

Comment: I guess it right, you are rotating the view, this is not used, now also the ipad frame size is 768X1024 so only cells inside the 768 working others are not working, you want to change the orientation for this view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this for change the orientation!!

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I change the orientation of subview only not the view controller??

Comment: you should change the view controller

Comment: @FadiaJaradat If it works can you give me a upvote:?

Answer (score 0):

While views can draw outside of their superview's bounds they cannot receive touch events.

You have to make sure that you table view and all its superviews cover the whole area of the screen. It looks like one of the superviews is rotated but not resized correctly. Check this by typing ...

```
po [myTableView.window recursiveDescription]
```

... in the debugger, for example at a breakpoint in your controller's `viewDidAppear`.

It's probably a good idea to switch to proper `UIViewController`, rootViewController, etc. usage instead of doing the rotation in your custom code. Your app will behave much more as expected.

Comment: Thank you Manimaran and Nikolai Ruhe I will change the orientation of view controller.